# Careers Support Page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

The [support page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/support) on the careers site has a broken link to "My Account". Also the text still references "paying customer".

Answer (score 3):

That link is under the section titled "Need to edit or remove a job listing?"  For the people who need it (employers who have purchased job listings) it isn't broken.  The text references "paying customer"s because the employers who use our site to find candidates pay us (I mean, we could give it away but if people are willing to pay us for our shenanigans we'll take it :))

Answer (score 0):

Changing the link to

> http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv

will do the trick, but maybe adding a route for

> http://careers.stackoverflow.com/account

which points to the same link might be a better idea to be "backwards compatible".

Concerning "paying customer": it's possible that this means "only employers (who pay) can use the careers@stackoverflow.com address, while candidates only have meta.stackoverflow.com as a support option".